# How to compare a char to array when the array is not full

Tags: java, arrays, char

So I'm trying to compare a char to an array of chars, the problems is when the array isn't full yet. I'm making a java program for advanced tic-tac-toe.

I've thought about using an ArrayList, but I need the type to char not a primitive type.

```
 char players = new char[numPlayers] // ex: numPlayers == 4

 getPlayers(numPlayers, players)
```

```
 private static void getPlayers(int numPlayers, char players[]){
    char temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the character to represent player " + (i + 1));
        temp = in.next().charAt(0);
        char upper = Character.toUpperCase(temp);
        players[i] = upper;
        if(!validatePlayer(upper, players)){
            System.out.println("Each character must be unique");
            getPlayers(numPlayers, players);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean validatePlayer(char upper, char players[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i ++){
        if(upper != players[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For first of all why don't use `players.length`, insted of `numPlayers`?

Comment: Yes, it is true that you cannot use the type `char` to create an `ArrayList`, but what you can do is use the wrapper class `Character`. It will behave like a `char` variable but sometimes you will have to use casts to make things work

Comment: @KunLun for which part?

Comment: Everywhere, you can get size(`numPlayers`) of an primitive array with `arr.length`. This advice is just for how to write code and doesn't make it better.

Comment: Also you can you `Character` if you need object of primitive `char`. Also, in future,  if you don't find what you want, you can create your own object which hold data you want. In your char a `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caller knows the length that has been filled so far, and can pass it.

```
   if (!validatePlayer(upper, players, i ))
```

The method can use this length, rather than the full length of the array.

```
private static boolean validatePlayer(char upper, char players[], int len ){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ...
    } 
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to initialize a char array is
`char[] players = new char[numPlayers];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
private static boolean validatePlayer(char upper, char players[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i ++){
        if(upper != players[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When `players.length == 0`, `for loop` will never be executed. And you get always `false`.

Also imagine if your `players` contains `'a'` and `'b'` and you call `validatePlayer('b', players)`:

```
1. for loop will get first element. `players[0]` -> 'a'
2. Compare 'b' != 'a' -> true
3. Return true.
```

`validatePlayer('b', players)` returns true, even if he has `'b'`.

I recommand you to change method like this:

```
private static boolean validatePlayer(char upper, char players[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < players.length; i ++){
        if(upper == players[i]){ //equal
            return false; //false
        }
    }
    return true; //true
}
```

Check if contains char, otherwise return true.

Comment: I noticed that and fixed it